# Image clip centre

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my image to be clipped in the centre and be able to move around left right up down while being on cover to fit the whole screen 
The user should be able to see only a certain portion of the image and be able to move around just like the link below but his viewpoint is the little rectangle in a fit to screen perspective
What i get so far is just the clipped upleft of my image

In case i am not clear what I am trying to achieve this effect but the user can't see move than the square
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_zoom.asp

I will soon close this ticket if you happen to stumble on this check out this q I believe I am as as clear as I can here
[How to clip your image freely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58079617/how-to-clip-your-image-freely?noredirect=1#comment102553689_58079617)

```
<style>
img {
    background-position: cover;
    position: absolute;
    clip:rect(0px,500px,500px,0px);
}
.image1 { 
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class='clipper-div'>
   <img class='image1' src='office.gif'/>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The kind you were looking for is an **inset** clipping:

```
clip-path: inset(top bottom left right);
```

You can listen to the mouse move event to update the clipping. In the example below, I used [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) I added to the clipper-element style definition.

These custom properties are used as CSS variables for the clipping definition.

```js
// Globals variables (we could store them into an object,
// which would be a cleaner way
var clipperDiv = document.getElementById("clipper-div");
var hoveringClippedImg = document.getElementById("hovering-clipped");
var imgBoundingRect = hoveringClippedImg.getBoundingClientRect();
var clippingSize = 40;

// Surrouding DIV element mouse move event callback
clipperDiv.onmousemove = clipHoveredArea;

// Update image clipping

function clipHoveredArea(e) {

  // First step: getting clipping coordinates from mouse position
  var pos = getMousePos(e);
  var top = (pos.y - clippingSize / 2);
  var bottom = (imgBoundingRect.height - pos.y - (clippingSize / 2));
  var left = (pos.x - clippingSize / 2);
  var right = (imgBoundingRect.width - pos.x - clippingSize / 2);

  // Second step: CSS custom properties
  hoveringClippedImg.style.setProperty("--top", top + "px");
  hoveringClippedImg.style.setProperty("--bottom", bottom + "px");
  hoveringClippedImg.style.setProperty("--left", left + "px");
  hoveringClippedImg.style.setProperty("--right", right + "px");

};

// Get mouse position relative to an element
// Source: //stackoverflow.com/a/42111623/4375327

function getMousePos(e) {
  // e = Mouse click event.
  var rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = e.clientX - Math.round(rect.left);
  var y = e.clientY - Math.round(rect.top);
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}
```

```css
#clipper-div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#hovering-clipped {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clip-path: inset(var(--top) var(--right) var(--bottom) var(--left));
  --top: 0px;
  --right: 0px;
  --bottom: 0px;
  --left: 0px;
  cursor: crosshair;
}
```

```html
<div id='clipper-div'>
  <img id="hovering-clipped"
       src="//placehold.it/200x200/d0d8f8/000000" />
</div>
```

---

Note: I used [Clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/). It's a handy tool to design the clipping you want.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer my question but this is not what i am looking for, the user should be able to see a certain portion lets say 200x200 of the image and move around

Comment: Thanks again. What I get is a placeholded image what I want to do is have a picture and let the user see the middle of it without cropping it using Ps or edit app. That is because I want the user to be able to move around and see the rest of the picture. All that is in the mobile version which i forgot to clarify

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58079617/how-to-clip-your-image-freely?noredirect=1#comment102553689_58079617

Comment: @scriver, this is another topic, it's about **event handling**. You can check this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43937223/4375327. If my answer suits the question _about_ clipping, could you please mark it as accepted?