# How to clip your image freely

Tags: javascript, html, css

1st of all this is about the mobile version of a site
My goal is to take an image clip it in it's center and make it free for the user to move left and right as he pleases

I believe I am the wrong foot and clip value shouldn't be used don't take my code and try to fix it may be completely wrong

I have an idea to hide the image left and right somehow but I don't know how to implement it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
  <style>
   .center-cropped {
    width: 500px;
    height: 800px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
   }

.center-cropped img {
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
/* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  /* IE 5-7 */
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 /* modern browsers */
 opacity: 0;
 }
 </style>
  </head>
<body>
 <script>

 </script>
<div class="center-cropped" style="background-image:     url('office.gif');">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check This links https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-clip.asp

Comment: what do you mean by freely? Are you looking for something like [cropit](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/) in a few lines of css?

Comment: @FrontEndCoder This looks like it but it fits my needs only if I can add 2 blocks of white left and right at my image and they don't show up in the browser only the image. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone You are the man. I want the image to maintain its properties though it should have its full height  and to only move left and right. I will try to find it on my own will get back to you with the answer

Comment: @scriver will you please share something about how you want to see the output

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I can't quite understand this code can you help me make it so this bar isn't there and I set the image?

Comment: @FrontEndCoder see Lawrence's link above the first picture but with 100% height

Comment: Oh and don't forget that this is mobile so you should be able to move left-right with scrolling and not this bar